# OpenCL enqueueNDRangeKernel causes Access Violation error

Tags: opencl

I am continuously getting an Access Violation Error with a all my kernels which I am trying to build. Other kernels which I take from books seem to work fine.

https://github.com/ssarangi/VideoCL - This is where the code is.

Something seems to be missing in this. Could someone help me with this.

Thanks so much.

[James] - Thanks for the suggestion and you are right. I am doing it on Win 7 with a AMD Redwood card. I have the Catalyst 11.7 drivers with AMD APP SDK 2.5. I am posting the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bmpfuncs.h"

#include "CLManager.h"

void main()
{
    float theta = 3.14159f/6.0f;
    int W ;
    int H ;

    const char* inputFile = "input.bmp";
    const char* outputFile = "output.bmp";

    float* ip = readImage(inputFile, &W, &H);
    float *op = new float[W*H];

    //We assume that the input image is the array “ip”
    //and the angle of rotation is theta
    float cos_theta = cos(theta);
    float sin_theta = sin(theta);

    try
    {
        CLManager* clMgr = new CLManager();

        // Build the Source
        unsigned int pgmID = clMgr->buildSource("rotation.cl");

        // Create the kernel
        cl::Kernel* kernel = clMgr->makeKernel(pgmID, "img_rotate");

        // Create the memory Buffers
        cl::Buffer* clIp = clMgr->createBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, W*H*sizeof(float));
        cl::Buffer* clOp = clMgr->createBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, W*H*sizeof(float));

        // Get the command Queue
        cl::CommandQueue* queue = clMgr->getCmdQueue();
        queue->enqueueWriteBuffer(*clIp, CL_TRUE, 0, W*H*sizeof(float), ip);

        // Set the arguments to the kernel
        kernel->setArg(0, clOp);
        kernel->setArg(1, clIp);
        kernel->setArg(2, W);
        kernel->setArg(3, H);
        kernel->setArg(4, sin_theta);
        kernel->setArg(5, cos_theta);

        // Run the kernel on specific NDRange
        cl::NDRange globalws(W, H);


        queue->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*kernel, cl::NullRange, globalws, cl::NullRange);

        queue->enqueueReadBuffer(*clOp, CL_TRUE, 0, W*H*sizeof(float), op);

        storeImage(op, outputFile, H, W, inputFile);
    }
    catch(cl::Error error)
    {
        std::cout << error.what() << "(" << error.err() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error at the queue->enqueueNDRangeKernel line. 
I have the queue and the kernel stored in a class.

```
CLManager::CLManager()
    : m_programIDs(-1)
{
    // Initialize the Platform
    cl::Platform::get(&m_platforms);

    // Create a Context
    cl_context_properties cps[3] = {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties)(m_platforms[0])(),
        0
    };

    m_context = cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, cps);

    // Get a list of devices on this platform
    m_devices = m_context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

    cl_int err;

    m_queue = new cl::CommandQueue(m_context, m_devices[0], 0, &err);
}


cl::Kernel* CLManager::makeKernel(unsigned int programID, std::string kernelName)
{
    cl::CommandQueue queue = cl::CommandQueue(m_context, m_devices[0]);

    cl::Kernel* kernel = new cl::Kernel(*(m_programs[programID]), kernelName.c_str());

    m_kernels.push_back(kernel);

    return kernel;
}
```

Comment: Hi, ssarangi.  You haven't mentioned enough to get serious help here.  You should tell us your platform and CL implementation, and post the problematic code, including what you've already done to get things working on your own.  Linking to an external repository is a bad idea, since that link might not be valid down the road.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked your code. I'm on Linux though. At runtime I'm getting Error `-38`, which means `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT`. So I went and checked your buffers.

```
cl::Buffer* clIp = clMgr->createBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, W*H*sizeof(float));
cl::Buffer* clOp = clMgr->createBuffer(CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, W*H*sizeof(float));
```

Then you pass the buffers as a Pointer:

```
kernel->setArg(0, clOp);
kernel->setArg(1, clIp);
```

**But** `setArg` is expecting a value, so the buffer pointers should be dereferenced:

```
kernel->setArg(0, *clOp);
kernel->setArg(1, *clIp);
```

After those changes the cat rotates ;)

Comment: The adding of the arrays probably worked ok with the code shown, as you'd pass the array (but actually a pointer to the first value) as the kernel argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was stupid of me to overlook this. This actually did fix the problem. Thanks again.